# Create a one to many relationship with data intregrety

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship

For example, if I create the following database table layout:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users_parent (
ID int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Username text NOT NULL,
Password text NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users_Child (
ID int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Firstname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
SecondName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
UserID int(255) NOT NULL,

)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users_OtherChild (
ID int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Warnings text NOT NULL,
UserID text NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

From reading, `UserID` would be the foreign key to establish a one to many relationship with all the other associated tables within the same schema.

I understand this runs within a stored procedure within the MySQL Database, but how would I forbid the row deletion in the parent table until all of the child tables are deleted so there would be no child information associated with the parent?

Comment: Are you looking for a DELETE on the parent table to cause cascading deletes in the child tables? OR are you tring to stop the deleting of the parent? (the implementation will depend heavily on the answer to this)

Comment: @Declan_K Prevent the deletion of the parent row until all child tables are clear of any associated data

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't answer the question (probably because I didn't ask it very well). When you say "until all child tables are clear of any associated data", are you expecting this deletion of associated date to happen automatically in the background, or do you want to alert the user that assoicated date exists and stop the delete on the parent?

Comment: @Declan_K Sorry for not being clear enough, it's only recently i've took an interest in the full options of SQL it's self, but preferably it'll be to run within the background & delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to propogate deletes from a parent table down to child tables you need to implement Foreign Keys with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html) for a detailed explaination of enforcing cascading deletes

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key will prevent any row (with the id) in the parent to be deleted while it has a child left (as in a row referencing it by the userid field) in any table referencing to the parent table.

Question is: why would you want to delete the child table? It's not needed in your example I think. As long as any child is left in that table the reference will hold.

Use the mysql documentation on how to create a foreign key:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html